# How to hide ImageView in ListView correctly?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, picasso

I want to add to ListView information about widgets:

```
public class Widget {
    String w_type;
    String title;
    String desc;
    String img;
    //....
}
```

I want to show image in listview if img field isn't empty and hide ImageView in ListView if it's empty. There is current code of getView method from my adapter for listview:

```
public View getView(int i, View someView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (someView == null) {
        someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widgets_list, arg2, false);
    }

    ImageView img = (ImageView) someView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    if (!img_url.equals("")){
       Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).into(img);
       }
       else {
           img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

    return someView;
}
```

It hiding ImageView not only when img field is empty but sometimes when it's not empty too. How can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you set your img_url? Can you provide code of that? Does every item in the list have a different img_url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ImageView is still hidden from an earlier call to `img.setVisibility(View.GONE);` so just re-show it again.

```
   if (!img_url.equals("")){
       Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).into(img);
           img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
       else {
           img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually Picasso makes a thread and load the images. The easiest way but instead you can make some call back functions like. 
in here

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .into(img, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }
                });
```